# Are there any existing C implementations having padding bit in (un)signed integer representation?

Tags: c, c99, bit-representation, padding-bit

As per C99, there maybe padding bits in `signed int`  or `unsigned int` representation . So I wonder are there still any implementations having such outdated things?

Comment: You might want to produce an example and related sections in C99 standard (latest draft might be OK)

Comment: @ydroneaud: See section 6.2.6.2: "For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits of the object
representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits", similarly for signed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting the C99 rationale ([PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf)) section 6.2.6.2 §20:

> Padding bits are user-accessible in an unsigned integer type. For example, suppose a machine
>   uses a pair of 16-bit shorts (each with its own sign bit) to make up a 32-bit `int` and the sign bit of the lower `short` is ignored when used in this 32-bit `int`. Then, as a 32-bit `signed int`, there is a padding bit (in the middle of the 32 bits) that is ignored in determining the value 20 of the 32-bit `signed int`. But, if this 32-bit item is treated as a 32-bit `unsigned int`, then that padding bit is visible to the user’s program. **The C committee was told that there is a machine that works this way, and that is one reason that padding bits were added to C99.**

So such things at least *did* exist.

As for weird architectures [still around today](http://www.unisys.com/unisys/theme/index.jsp?id=1120000970018010225), the go-to example is the UNIVAC 1100/2200 series with its [weird data formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series#Data_formats).

While it does *not* use integer padding, a look at their C compiler manual ([PDF](http://public.support.unisys.com/2200/docs/cp12.0/pdf/78310422-010.pdf)) is still instructive:

```
Table 4–4. Size and Range of Unsigned Integer Types

Type                 Size        Range
unsigned short int   18 bits     0 to (2^18)–1
unsigned short

unsigned int         36 bits     0 to (2^36)–2 (see the following note)
unsigned

unsigned long int    36 bits     0 to (2^36)–2 (see the following note)
unsigned long
```

The second volume ([PDF](http://public.support.unisys.com/2200/docs/CP12.0/PDF/78310430-014.pdf)) explains how the `CONFORMANCE/TWOSARITH` compiler keyword can be used to control interpretation of negative zero: this adjusts the range of the unsigned integer types to the expected (2^36)-1 but comes with a performance penalty on unsigned arithmetics.

Comment: Giving `unsigned int` a range of 0 to 2^36-2 is actually non-conforming. If it uses all 36 bits of a 36-bit word as value bits, then it has to be able to represent all 2^36 distinct values.

Answer (score 16):

From [The New C Standard](http://www.knosof.co.uk/cbook/cbook.html):

> On some Cray processors the type short has 32 bits of precision but is held in 64 bits worth of storage. The Unisys A Series unsigned integer type contains a padding bit that is treated as a sign bit in the signed integer representation.
>
> ...
>
> The Harris/6 computer represented the type long using two consecutive int types. This meant that the sign bit of one of the ints had to be ignored; it was treated as a padding bit. The value representation of the type int is 24 bits wide, and long had a value representation of 47 bits with one padding bit.

Comment: +1: nice to finally get a name for the '*machine that works this way*'

Answer (score 3):

The [MSP430X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430X_20-bit_extension) architecture (an architecture for microcontrollers from Texas Instruments) is a 16 bit architecture (MSP430) expanded to a 20 bit address space with 20 bit registers. The architecture is still byte-addressed with one byte having eight bits. Instructions can generally operate on quantities of 8, 16, and 20 bits.

On this architecture, a compiler might choose to make `int` a 20 bit type. Since 20 is not a multiple of 8, 4 or 12 bits of padding have to be added when storing this type in memory.

Comment: Nice example, thanks. Incidentally, the GCC port for the MSP430(X) uses "20-bit pointers, 32-bit size_t" ( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MSP430-Options.html#MSP430-Options ).

Comment: @sleske Recently a patch was committed that adds a 20 bit `uint20_t` and uses that type for `size_t` and `uintptr_t`. I don't think there has been a stable release with that patch yet though.