# How to print 32 bit value complete?

Tags: c, kernel, hex

I want to know that how to print the complete integer value with zero also in C only.

And i am in kernel space ,want to print some values in kernel module.

Like if `a` is a 32 bit integer then

`int a = 14`

then output will be like this

`value of a = 0x0000000e`

in hexa-decimal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note, you'll get `0000000E` if you use `%08X` and `0000000e` if you use `%08x`. Big X does big ABCDEF and little x does little abcdef. I prefer the caps style myself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put a `0` in the format:

```
printf("value of a = 0x%08x", a);
```

From the [`printf(3)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/):

> **`'0'`** *(zero)*
>
> Zero padding.  For all conversions except **`n`**, the converted value is padded on the left with zeros rather
>                         than blanks.  If a precision is given with a numeric
>                         conversion (**`d`**, **`i`**, **`o`**, **`u`**, **`i`**, **`x`**, and **`X`**), the 0 flag is
>                         ignored.

Nothing like the documentation to answer questions for you - at least if the documentation is any good.

Comment: ... and if the documentation is any good, it'll tell you that an *unsigned int* corresponds, and "If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined." (§7.21.6.1p9 of n1570.pdf)...

Comment: That's true, strictly speaking.  In practice, are you aware of any implementations that don't behave reasonably?  That is, as if there were an explicit cast?

Comment: +1 but perhaps one should note also that there is `#` as a modifier for an "alternate" form that provides the `0x` in front.

Comment: @CarlNorum [I guess so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120197/are-there-any-existing-c-implementations-having-padding-bit-in-unsigned-intege/)...

Comment: @CarlNorum The problem is that `printf` is a variadic function, and because of this there is no conversion from `int` to `unsigned int`, implicit or explicit. Push an `int`, pop an `unsigned int` with the exact same representation... Hence, `printf("%X\n", -1);` will also invariably react differently depending upon whether ones complement, twos complement or sign-and-magnitude representation is used, in addition to the possibility for padding in the integer representation to have an impact, as raised in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with the reasoning.  I just wondered if you'd ever really experienced the problem in practice.  It seems like there's a lot of convergence on some of these technically nonstandard things.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a = 14;

  printf("value of a = 0x%08x\n", a);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//print 32 bit no in hex
 uint32_t n = 0x10203040;
 printf("32_bit no 0x%08x",n);


32_bit no 0x10203040
```