# Are there any examples of architectures in which int cannot represent all values of unsigned short despite latter being shorter?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, integer, short

Are there any known examples of architectures out there in which unsigned short is smaller than int yet still only representable by unsigned int after conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sane compiler would make this possible<sup>(1)</sup>.

If `int` is even one bit wider than `short`, it can represent all values of `short` and `unsigned short`. For example:

- if `unsigned short` is 16-bit, it can represent [0, 2<sup>16</sup>)
- if `signed int` is one bit wider, it can represent [-2<sup>16</sup>, 2<sup>16</sup>) <sup>(2)</sup>

See also [[basic.fundamental] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#3).

You're probably asking because of the promotion rules to `int`/`unsigned int` from narrower types.
If `int` and `short` have the same amount of bits, then `unsigned short` gets promoted to `unsigned int`.
16-bit architectures typically have a 16-bit `int` and 16-bit `short`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *Technically*, it's possible that `int` is larger (in terms of `sizeof`) than `unsigned short` but not any wider (in terms of what values it can represent) because integers are allowed to have padding bits. However, it would be utterly nonsensical for `int` to be larger despite not being wider, so no sane compiler would do this.

<sup>(2)</sup> Prior to C++20, the guaranteed lower bound for 17-bit `int` would only be -2<sup>16</sup>+1.

Comment: "_However, it would be utterly nonsensical for int to be larger despite not being wider_": While I don't have any counterexample, I don't think that's so obvious. The other way around, i.e. same size, but different width, for `int` and `short` did apparently exist on some Cray implementations according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14121722/17732522.